# Insert sql error ("where")

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I created some simple code, but it looks like something is working wrong with my Insert I get error about "where". What did I do wrong?

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conStr"].ConnectionString);
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
  "insert  into dbo.UserInfo (Login, Password, UserType, ID) where Login =@Login and Password=@Password  and Type=@UserType ", con);
{
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Login",TextBox1.Text );
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", TextBox2.Text+".123");
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);

  int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

  con.Close(); 
}
```

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.

Comment: use update instead of insert if you are trying to update a row or else leave the where clause

Comment: You did not write the values you only define the columns so it gives the error at WHERE. Just add the values before Where

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SQL Insert` Into statement is

```
INSERT INTO Table_Name ( Col1, Col2, Col3) 
VALUES ( Val1, Val2, Val3);
```

I think,

```
insert into dbo.UserInfo (Login, Password, UserType, ID) 
where Login =@Login and Password=@Password  and Type=@UserType "
```

try to change the code to this.

Answer (score 2):

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conStr"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
            "insert  into dbo.UserInfo (Login, Password, UserType, ID) " +
              " VALUES(@Login,@Password,@UserType) ", con);
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Login",TextBox1.Text );
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", TextBox2.Text+".123");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);

                int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

              con.Close(); 
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT` statements don't have `WHERE` clauses, `UPDATE` statements do.

Answer (score 1):

You would only use a WHERE clause if there was an actual select statement.

Something like

```
insert  into dbo.UserInfo (Login, Password, UserType, ID) 
SELECT  Login, Password, UserType, ID
FROM    Table
where   Login =@Login 
and     Password=@Password  
and     Type=@UserType
```

Otherwise you just use the values. Something like

```
insert  into dbo.UserInfo (Login, Password, UserType, ID) 
VALUES (@Login,@Password,@UserType, @ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) VALUES (value1, value2)
```

Your query should probably be

```
"insert  into dbo.UserInfo (Login, Password, UserType, ID) values (@Login, @Password, @UserType)"
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are using where while inserting single record to table. Below is the proper code to insert

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conStr"].ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                string sql = "INSERT INTO UserInfo(Login, Password, UserType) VALUES(@Login,@Password,@Type)";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Login", TextBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", TextBox2.Text + ".123");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Please, follow below syntex: 
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);

=============
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conStr"].ConnectionString);
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
  "insert  into dbo.UserInfo (Login, Password, UserType) values(@Login,@Password,@UserType) ", con);
{
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Login",TextBox1.Text );
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", TextBox2.Text+".123");
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);

  int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

  con.Close(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) VALUES (value1, value2)
```

Only check your Insert Syntax you will get the answer :

```
"insert  into dbo.xyz(Login, Password, ID) values (@Login, @Password)"
```

**dbo:xyz = your table name**